# how to set holo UI theme without action bar in android 2.3 and above

Tags: android, android-theme, android-holo-everywhere

Is there a way to use Holo theme in android 2.3 without using actionBar with it. I tried using Holoeverywhere library but it is showing actionbarbar as well.
Also I want the Holo UI same throughout the app no matter which OS version user is on (2.3.3 and above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply theme `Holo.Theme.NoActionBar` on activity. For decrease a memory leak you can disable abs by setting `requireSherlock = false` in `onCreateConfig`, like in demo.